# Eclipse Add Perspective to Runtime

Tags: eclipse, runtime, perspective, oxygenxml

I'm creating a content analysis plugin for Eclipse and I'm testing it in Eclipse by running Eclipse Application.

This worked well (since my plugin only had to work with a plain text editor), but now my company has stepped over to using oXygen as XML plugin in Eclipse for our technical writers. To test whether my plugin also works with oXygen in use, I need to have the oXygen XML Author plugin working in the Runtime.

I have oXygen working in my main Eclipse, but that is not what I want: I need it in my Runtime Environment.

So my question is: how can I add this oXygen plugin to the Eclipse Runtime Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your debug/run configuration -> Select the configuration in question.
Go to plug ins tab. Check if the Oxygen plugin is in the list. If not then add it explicitly and launch the runtime again.

Hope it helps.

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: Thanks. Your answer led me the right direction: I didn't add it to the Dependencies (Required Plug-ins) list, so I couldn't see it...